# Create boolean column showing if value falls within n consecutive nonzero rows: how to improve performance of this code?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a column of "Activation" values, that are sometimes positive and sometime zero. I would like to create three other columns to identify the consecutive non-zero Activations, where they are in a sequence of :

- at least four
- at least eight
- or at least sixteen

So far I have the following code, but which works but it is pretty tortured and the last line is very slow. How could I speed this up?

```
    df["consecutive_activations_count"] =df["UpAssetEnergyMWh"].groupby(df["UpAssetEnergyMWh"].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()

    df["consecutive_activations_count_daily_max"] = df.resample("D")["consecutive_activations_count"].transform("max")

    df["is_in_four_consecutive_activations"] = ((df["consecutive_activations_count"].shift(-3).rolling(4)).apply(lambda x: any(x >= 4)))
```

```
UpAssetEnergyMWh    consecutive_activations_count   consecutive_activations_count_daily_max is_in_four_consecutive_activations  is_in_eight_consecutive_activations is_in_sixteen_consecutive_activations 
0       0   4   0   0   0 
0       0   4   0   0   0 
0       0   4   0   0   0 
0       0   4   0   0   0 
0       0   4   0   0   0
0.1     1   4   1   0   0
0.25    2   4   1   0   0
0.25    3   4   1   0   0
0.25    4   4   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not very familiar with pandas library, but i think i can help u with the performance bit.

My idea is to just store `maximum_consecutive_actions` column, which stores the maximum number of consecutive actions which this element is in. This can be done quite simply with your `consecutive_actions_count` column.

The `i`th row of the `maximum_consecutive_actions` column is simply equal to max(`i`th row of `consecutive_actions_count` column, `i-1`th row of `maximum_consecutive_actions` column).

Notice that since to calculate the `i`th column, u need the `i-1` the column, so u have to compute this from bottom-up.

The rest of the columns `is_in_four_consecutive_activations`, `is_in_eight_consecutive_activations`, and `is_in_sixteen_consecutive_activations` can be computed very easily and quickly from the `maximum_consecutive_actions` column. However, these columns may not even be needed which is something u can consider.

Do let me know if I can improve my answer in any way as im not familiar with the pandas library.

Comment: Thanks ChickenCoding! I didn't understand exactly what you meant about the ith rows. What is the difference between the maximum_consecutive_actions column you propose and the consecutive_activations_count_daily_max ?

Comment: @arj in the table you gave, the column would store.

0
0
0
0
0
4
4
4
4
I hope this example clarifies what maximum_consecutive_actions stores. It stores the maximum length of a sequence of consecutive actions such that this element is part of that sequence.